# assign a column value to another column

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to assign a column value to another column using case when.

Here, I want to assign 'CountAll' column to another columns.

I tried to fix it but it gives me an error like 'invalid identifier'. Need your help.

```
select cast(sysdate  as timestamp(0)) SAMPLE_TIME, SQL_ID, Count(*) as "CountAll", WAIT_TIME, WAIT_CLASS,
case when wait_time!=0 then 1 end as "CPU",
case when wait_time=0 and wait_class='Scheduler' then CountAll end as "Scheduler",
case when wait_time=0 and wait_class='User I/O' then Count1 end as "User I/O",
case when wait_time=0 and wait_class='System I/O' then Count1 end as "System I/O",
case when wait_time=0 and wait_class='Concurrency' then Count1 end as "Concurrency"
FROM  gv$session
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results that you want to achiever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you want something like this:

```
select cast(sysdate  as timestamp(0)) as SAMPLE_TIME, SQL_ID,
       Count(*) as CountAll, 
       sum(case when wait_time <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as "CPU",
       sum(case when wait_time = 0 and wait_class = 'Scheduler' then 1 else 0 end) as Scheduler,
       sum(case when wait_time = 0 and wait_class = 'User I/O' then 1 else 0 end) as "User I/O",
       sum(case when wait_time = 0 and wait_class = 'System I/O' then 1 else 0 end) as "System I/O",
       sum(case when wait_time = 0 and wait_class = 'Concurrency' then 1 else 0 end) as "Concurrency"
FROM gv$session
GROUP BY cast(sysdate  as timestamp(0)) as SAMPLE_TIME, SQL_ID;
```